# Excel vlookup matching on last column and return row

Tags: excel

In excel I have a table on sheet 1:

[image: Excel table]

Within sheet 2 I want to do something like a vlookup which looks for 'not done'in the status column and if found then the whole row is shown in sheet 2.  Also an added complication is that I would prefer not to have gaps i.e. for any rows showing 'done' as below:

[image: Amended excel table]

As I state above I have been trying with VLOOKUP and CHOOSE but I cant get anything to work.  Can anyone suggest some ideas?

Comment: Use vba, filter then copy.  If your data set is large the number of Array Type Formula will cause an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CSE formula (entered with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>).

If your data is in `A1:C7` (including header row), you can put this in `E2` and drag right and down:

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$7,SMALL(IF($C$2:$C$7="not done",ROW(A$2:A$7)-ROW(A$2)+1),ROWS(A$2:A2)))
```

Wrap that in `IFERROR([formula above],"")` to hide `#NUM` errors when it runs out of results.

[image]

Comment: thanks for that.  Is there a way of expanding it.  So the original table replicated 3 times and it looks for 'not done' in the third column of each table and produces a list from all three?